# JSOM create several columns but skipping

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jsom

I was given a spreadsheet with the names of 85 departments. They want a list where each department will have 3 text boxes to be filled in with a numeric value. Example:
[image]

As you can tell when you do the math, I will have to create 255 columns.  I refuse to do that, so with the help of stackexchange, I created code using JSOM that allowed me to create the columns dynamically.  Here's my problem, not all the columns were created.  When I ran the code, maybe about 75 columns or so were missing and they were not the same 75 or so every time I recreated the columns. Here's part image of what was generated showing the missing columns.
[image]

As you can see, there are several gaps.  When I console.log() the error, here's what I received.  ***Request failed. The specified program requires a newer version of Windows. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007047E)***

Here's the code that you can even run yourself to test.

```
departMentNames=[];

function getColumnNames() {
//Department Test contains all 85 department names
    var endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Department Test')/items?$select=Title,ID";

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: endPointUrl,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
        //alert(data);
            detailComplete(data); // Returns JSON collection of the results
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("Error Occured:" + JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
}


function detailComplete(data) {
for (var i=0; i<data.d.results.length; i++)
{
    departMentNames.push(data.d.results[i].Title.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, ""));
}

var gsf = ["Before", "After", "Delta"];
var newFieldNames =[];
var z=0;

//Create the 255 fields in the list
for(var x=0; x<departMentNames.length; x++) {
    for(var y=0; y<gsf.length; y++) {
            addFields(departMentNames[x]+gsf[y]);
    }
}
}

getColumnNames();

function addFields(NewField) {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
//Getting reference to the list where I will create 255 columns
oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test 2');

// Get filed collection
var fldCollection = oList.get_fields();

var f1 = clientContext.castTo(fldCollection.addFieldAsXml('<Field Type="Text" DisplayName="'+NewField+'" Name="'+NewField+'" />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.addToDefaultContentType), SP.FieldText);
console.log("About to set the field");

f1.update();
f1.set_title(NewField);
//f1.set_description("sample desc");

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
console.log("List Field Updated");
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + 
args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Does anyone know why all the columns aren't being created?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like these requirements can be solved in a simpler way without the use of code.  Why not have a column called "Department Name", make it a choice field with all of your department choices.  Then 3 Single Line of Text columns, call them "Before", "Delta", and "After".  Add 85 items to the list, each item representing a different department.

Comment: I agree with you but the problem is, the client wants to see all 85 on the screen.  I know, it's insane.

Comment: If that's the case, I would modify the Item Limit on your default view to show all 85 items.  You aren't limited to the top 30.

Comment: Also, OP states that they should have numeric values... so... why not make them Number fields instead of Text?  And then you can make the Delta field a calculated column that calculates the difference between Before and After automatically...

Comment: I see where you all are going with this. It makes sense.  One slight detail I accidentally left out.  So there will be hundreds of projects and each project will need what I described above.  How do you think I can set that up?

Comment: @JustMe does one project belong to just one Department?  If so,  I would probably just create another column for Project.  That way you can filter by Department and see all projects for that Department, or filter by Project to see a specific set of projects (no matter what department they belong to) next to each other, etc.  If multiple departments are working on the same project, that's a different story, and you may want to think of a different way to organize the data. If *all* 85 departments work on *every* project, you may want to have a separate list per project.